# CMake + MinGW64 + Clang++ on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, clang++

I would like to compile an application with using Clang++ 10.0, CMake 3.10.1, MinGW x86_64 8.1.0.  in Windows 10.I've tried this in the build folder which is in the project folder:

```
cmake ../  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make -DCMAKE_GENERATOR="MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_RC_COMPILER=make
```

I can compile through cmake，the result is :

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/LLVM/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/LLVM/bin/clang.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/workspace/CompileTest/build
```

However, when I tried make, it's wrong:

```
Scanning dependencies of target CC_COMPILE_02
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CC_COMPILE_02.dir/main.cpp.obj
In file included from D:\workspace\CompileTest\main.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\iostream:9:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\yvals_core.h:847:1: error: static_assert failed
      "Error in C++ Standard Library usage."
_EMIT_STL_ERROR(STL1000, "Unexpected compiler version, expected Clang 16.0.0 or newer.");
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include\yvals_core.h:502:5: note: expanded from macro '_EMIT_STL_ERROR'
    static_assert(false, "Error in C++ Standard Library usage.")
    ^             ~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\CC_COMPILE_02.dir\build.make:62: CMakeFiles/CC_COMPILE_02.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/CC_COMPILE_02.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:83: all] Error 2
```

my CMakeLists.txt is here:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
# set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET "x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
# set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET "x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
# set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "D:/LLVM/bin/clang.exe")
# set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "D:/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe")

project(CC_COMPILE_02)
#add_compile_options(-target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g")
add_executable(CC_COMPILE_02 main.cpp Tokens/LexerToken.cpp Tokens/LexerToken.h Lexer/Lexer.cpp Lexer/Lexer.h Parser/Parser.cpp Parser/Parser.h Tokens/AbstractToken.cpp Tokens/AbstractToken.h Tokens/ParserToken.cpp Tokens/ParserToken.h Exceptions/CompileException.h Symbol/AbstractSymbol.h Symbol/SymbolTable.h Symbol/IntentSymbol.h Symbol/ArraySymbol.h Symbol/FuncSymbol.h Symbol/SymbolTableController.h)
```

I think the linker uses the MSVC's library but I already specified using mingw in cmake, I don't know where is wrong and want to fix it.

I have put mingw and llvm 's bin folder,include folder and lib folder into the environment variables.

Comment: A simple answer is to reinstall Clang and MinGW from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), their Clang uses the correct target by default. (But it's of course still interesting how to make CMake pass the correct flag.)

Answer (score 0):

I just used another method to declare cmake parameters and finally passed，here is my changed instruction and the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -target x86_64-w64-mingw32")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 ")

project(CC_COMPILE_02)
#add_compile_options(-target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g")
add_executable(CC_COMPILE_02 main.cpp Tokens/LexerToken.cpp Tokens/LexerToken.h Lexer/Lexer.cpp Lexer/Lexer.h Parser/Parser.cpp Parser/Parser.h Tokens/AbstractToken.cpp Tokens/AbstractToken.h Tokens/ParserToken.cpp Tokens/ParserToken.h Exceptions/CompileException.h Symbol/AbstractSymbol.h Symbol/SymbolTable.h Symbol/IntentSymbol.h Symbol/ArraySymbol.h Symbol/FuncSymbol.h Symbol/SymbolTableController.h)
```

and this is my instruction:

```
cmake ../  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make -DCMAKE_GENERATOR="MinGW Makefiles"
```

But I still don't know why it passed.
If I delete these two lines in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -target x86_64-w64-mingw32")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 ")
```

Or I delete this in the instruction:

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET=x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

It still can't pass. I thought these two things had the same effect before and the result confused me a lot. I am a newcomer to CMake and I am not very clear about the difference between defining compilation parameters in instructions and in the CMakeLists.txt file. During this process, I often found that defining compilation parameters in CMakeList.txt did not work and could only be defined on the command line. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but it seems that, setting the compiler is best done through the command line: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/proper-way-to-set-compiler-and-language-standard-in-cmake/2756.

Comment: Or a toolchain file. You shouldn't hardcode those details into the CMakeLists.txt itself to keep it portable.